# Unzipping multiple files without overwriting identically-named files

Tags: bash, filenames, zip

At an early stage of my script, it needs to unzip "x" amount of files provided by the user. Across the zipped file set, there are name-duplicates (but their contents differ from each other); i.e. both zip1.zip and zip2.zip contain the identically-named file "d09483272".

One could just unzip multiple files by doing `unzip \*zip -d $M_DIR` but this is inefficient -for my case- as newly decompressed files overwrite those already in the $M_DIR location.

Thought about decompressing them with a timestamp - some weird nested loop like the following (which clearly doesn't work)

```
    for zip in *zip; do
            unzip -l *zip | while read file
            do
                    unzip -p *.zip ${file} > $(date "+%H:%M:%S:%s%N").pdf
            done
    done
```

If this is not an appropriate approach, probably there is a simpler way of doing this? Thoughts?

Comment: Why not unzip each zip file to a different folder?

Comment: What do you *want* to end up with, for the duplicates?

Comment: The contents of all files -including the "name-duplicates" will be processed and pieced together at a later by the script - so no file should be left behind sort to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rushed into a non-elegant quick fix, due to time constraint.

```
    for zip in $T_DIR*zip; do
            unzip $zip -d $M_DIR;
            rename "s/.pdf/$(date "+%s%N").pdf/" ${M_DIR}*;
    done
```

Each file is individually unzipped onto the `$T_DIR` folder, followed by adding a nano-second timestamp to their names. When the next wave of unzipped files come into the `$T_DIR` folder, there will no longer be any "name-duplicate". Thoughts on a faster/ improved solution?

This would only work with the caveat that the "name-duplicates" files exist in separate zip files.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `unzip`-manpage:

```
 -n     never overwrite existing files.  If a file already exists, skip the extraction
        of that file without prompting.
```

Comment: Thanks, I did check but unfortunately the -n option doesn't work in this case because I would need the contents of both files - even though these may seem as duplicates, their contents differ from each other.